# Starting threads from inside EDT event handler code in Swing apps

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, java-8, event-dispatch-thread

My understanding of the Swing **Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT)** is that its a dedicated thread where event handling code is executed. So, if my understanding is correct, then in the example below:

```java
private class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      // START EDT
      String command = e.getActionCommand();  

      if( command.equals( "OK" ))  {
         statusLabel.setText("Ok Button clicked.");
      } else if( command.equals( "Submit" ) )  {
         statusLabel.setText("Submit Button clicked.");
      } else {
         statusLabel.setText("Cancel Button clicked.");
      }     
      // END EDT
   }        
}
```

All the code in between `START EDT` and `END EDT` is executing on the EDT, and any code outside of it is executing on the main application thread. Similarly, another example:

```java
// OUTSIDE EDT
JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Java SWING Examples");
mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
      // START EDT
      System.exit(0);
      // END EDT
   }        
   // BACK TO BEING OUTSIDE THE EDT
});
```

Again, only the `System.exit(0)` is executed inside the EDT.

**So for starters, if my understanding of the "division of labor" between EDT and main app thread code execution is incorrect, please begin by correcting me!**

Now then, I came across an article that emphasized the use of creating a new `Thread` from inside all this EDT code, which would make my first example above look like this:

```java
public class LabelUpdater implements Runnable {
  private JLabel statusLabel;
  private ActionEvent actionEvent;

  // ctor omitted here for brevity

  @Override
  public void run() {
    String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();  

    if (command.equals( "OK" ))  {
       statusLabel.setText("Ok Button clicked.");
    } else if( command.equals( "Submit" ) )  {
       statusLabel.setText("Submit Button clicked.");
    } else {
       statusLabel.setText("Cancel Button clicked.");
    }   
  }
}

private class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      // START EDT
      Thread thread = new Thread(new LabelUpdater(statusLabel, e));
      thread.start();
      // END EDT
   }        
}
```

My question: what advantage (or lack thereof) is there to this approach? Should I *always* code my EDT code this way, or is there a rubric one needs to follow as a guidelines for *when* to apply it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whether code outside an event listener is executed on the EDT or not depends on how that code is executed. For instance, you can use `SwingUtilities#invokeLater(Runnable)` to invoke anything on the EDT. But yes, event listeners that are invoked by the user interacting with the GUI will be executed on the EDT. As for the benefit of using a separate thread, it keeps the EDT free to continue processing the GUI; if a long-running task is executed on the EDT then the GUI will freeze (i.e. become non-responsive) while that task executes. However, updates to the GUI **must** be done on the EDT.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw (+1) a few followup questions if you don't mind: **(1)** if this "Thread strategy" that I proposed helps free the EDT from freezing (and thus has merit to it), then can a `SwingWorker` help here as well? Or is `SwingWorker` and my proposed "Thread strategy" meant to be used differently/elsewhere from one another? **(2)** To confirm: `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` can be used from outside the EDT to update the GUI inside the EDT, **correct**? And finally **(3)** Is `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` the intended way to communicate back to EDT from another thread? Thanks again!

Comment: **(1)** Yes. The reason to use `SwingWorker` is that it provides a built-in API for publishing messages/progress/state/results/etc back to the EDT. If you invoke `SwingWorker#execute()` then it schedules the task with an internal thread pool of "worker threads". You can of course still use your own threads, but consider using a thread pool over creating a new thread on demand. **(2)** Correct. **(3)** Yes. **(4 - Bonus)** Read [Marco13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58099865/6395627), it provides much more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is a bit broad and unspecific, but I'll try to address some of the points that you asked about. The entry point for further, own research is probably the [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), although it may indeed be hard to derive definite statements for specific cases from that.

First of all, there is an overarching rule in Swing - referred to as the **Single Thread Rule**:

> Once a Swing component has been realized, all code that might affect or depend on the state of that component should be executed in the event-dispatching thread.

<sup>(Unfortunately, it is no longer stated so clearly in the tutorial)</sup>

---

Keeping that in mind, looking at your snippets:

```
// OUTSIDE EDT
JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Java SWING Examples");
...
```

This is often true, unfortunately - and unfortunately, even in some of the official Swing examples. But this may already cause problems. To be on the safe side, the GUI (including the main frame) should always be handled on the EDT, using [`SwingUtilities#invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-). The pattern is always the same then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
}

private static void createAndShowGui() {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Java SWING Examples");
    ...
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

Regarding the second example that you showed, involving the `LabelUpdater` class: I'd be curious from which article you got this. I know, there is a lot of cr4p out there, but this example doesn't even remotely make sense...

```
public class LabelUpdater implements Runnable {
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        statusLabel.setText("Ok Button clicked.");
    }
}
```

**If** this code (i.e. the `run` method) is executed in an new thread, then it obviously violates the *single thread rule*: The status of the the `JLabel` is modified from a thread that is *not* the event dispatch thread!

---

The main point of starting a new thread in an event handler (e.g. in an `actionPerformed` method of an `ActionListener`) is to prevent *blocking the user interface*. If you had some code like this

```
someButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    doSomeComputationThatTakesFiveMinutes();
    someLabel.setText("Finished");
});
```

then pressing the button would cause the EDT to be blocked for 5 minutes - i.e. the GUI would "freeze", and look like it hung up. In these cases (i.e. when you have long-running computations), you should do the work in an own thread.

The naive approach of doing this manually *could* (roughly) look like this:

```
someButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    startBackgroundThread();
});

private void startBackgroundThread() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        doSomeComputationThatTakesFiveMinutes();
        someLabel.setText("Finished");              // WARNING - see notes below!
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Now, pressing the button would start a new thread, and the GUI would no longer block. But note the `WARNING` in the code: Now there's this problem again of the `JLabel` being modified by a thread that is *not* the event dispatch thread! So you'd have to pass this back to the EDT:

```
private void startBackgroundThread() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        doSomeComputationThatTakesFiveMinutes();

        // Do this on the EDT again...
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            someLabel.setText("Finished");
        });
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

This may look clumsy and complicated, and as if you could have a hard time figuring out on which thread you currently are. And that's right. But for the common task of starting a long-running task, there is the [`SwingWorker` class explained in the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) that makes this pattern somewhat simpler.

---

Shameless self-promotion: A while ago, I created a [`SwingTasks` library](https://github.com/javagl/SwingTasks), which is basically a "Swing Worker on steroids". It allows you to "wire up" methods like this...

```
SwingTaskExecutors.create(
    () -> computeTheResult(),
    result -> receiveTheResult(result)
).build().execute();
```

and takes care of showing a (modal) dialog if the execution takes too long, and offers some other convenience methods, e.g. for showing a progress bar in the dialog and so on. The samples are summarized at https://github.com/javagl/SwingTasks/tree/master/src/test/java/de/javagl/swing/tasks/samples

Comment: For a simple setup, `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::computeString) .thenAcceptAsync(someLabel::setText, SwingUtilities::invokeLater);`…

Comment: @Holger That's fine for the really *most* simple case (not significantly more concise than the manual `new Thread/invokeLater` calls, but a bit more elgant and "fluent"). However, as soon as a dialog, a progress bar or a 'Cancel' button are supposed to be involved, things become tricky...

Comment: Yes; your library looks interesting. Though, in my experience, the actual real life scenarios are so different, that attempting to serve them all through a framework rarely works. But a good starting point for those, who haven’t dealt with such problems before.

Comment: @Holger Sure, there is no one-fits-all solution. E.g. one functionality that I considered adding there would be to offer a "task list" like that of Eclipse etc: A component (NOT a modal dialog) that shows the "queue" of pending tasks, cancellable individually. But I did not feel the strong need for that yet: An (optionally modal) dialog with simple progress reporting and cancelling option covers 90% of most (and essentially 100% of my) use cases. Who is using Swing nowadays, anyhow? ;-)

Comment: Well, we use Swing and I don’t see any real alternative. And I’m not sad about the slow (or almost absent) development, as that implies that all the workarounds and tools built atop it continue to work, which is much better than new features every few weeks breaking existing code…